# Jetbrains Exposed support for Common Table Expressions

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-exposed

I have two tables where second table is referenced as foreign key in first table and I'm using jetbrains exposed as ORM framework for my Kotlin code.

Table A

```
id | type | tableb_id
1  | abcd | 2
2  | abcd | 3
```

Table B

```
id | date        | time
1  | 2022-12-12  | 2022-05-16 22:47:56.779378
```

The query I'm trying to achieve is

```
 WITH cte AS
(
       SELECT *
       FROM   a
       WHERE  type = 'abcd'), 
cte2 AS
(
         SELECT   *
         FROM     b
         WHERE    id IN (cte.tableb_id)
         ORDER BY date DESC,
                  time DESC limit 1)
SELECT *
FROM   cte
WHERE  tableb_id = cte2.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems that Exposed doesn't support CTEs at the moment. They have opened ticket from 2018 in their github: https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/issues/423